# AddIn для Visio 2010 в VS 2019

Tags: c#, visio

Можно ли с помощью VS 2019 сделать AddIn для Visio 2010? Дело в том, что в списке доступных шаблонов проектов есть только шаблоны для 2013 и выше.
У меня все пользователи сидят пока на 2010 Ofiice.

Просмотрел документацию по созданию AddIn по VS 2019. В ней упоминается AddIn для Visio 2010, но такого шаблона в списке нет. Все компоненты для Office для office установлены. Что делать?

Comment: Быть может пользователей пересадить все-таки на что-то посвежее, чем софт 10-летней давности?

Comment: Я не спец, просто предполагаю, что чтобы написать addin вам нужна возможность его запустить в том окружении, в котором вы его эксплуатировать будете, то есть в vs2010.

Comment: Рано или поздно любой софт/версия перестаются поддерживаться.  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: @aepot пользоватетей не всегда можно пересадить. Софт может быть платный и банально не быть лицухи. Руководство может отказать в покупке лицухи. А против руководства уже особо не пойдёшь.

Comment: Попробуйте скачайте и установите соответствующее  Visio 2010 SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12365 Если шаблон не появится, то прийдется мучатся с библиотеками из SDK вручную, но по идее должен появится. Возможно SDK подходит под более ранние версии VS

Comment: @nick_n_a пиратский софт - не оправдание. Спиратить можно любую версию любой свежести. А лицензионный софт дефакто должен быть свежим. А ситуации с использованием Windows 95/98/XP из-за того, что старый комп, я не рассматриваю. А по факту - это скорее именно либо ленивое IT, либо его отсутствие. И я бы не советовал в наше время айтишнику работать в компании, где используется пиратское ПО, это уголовщина, и первым загремит именно айтишник. Данный вопрос из разряда "как пропатчить KDE2 под FreeBSD?", но мы все уже знаем, что KDE на FreeBSD уже давно ставится без патчей.

Comment: Ну тут можно спорить долго.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел. Есть пакет **Extended Visio Addin  Project** Который позволяет создавать для Visio 2010.
Для @aepot. Кто сказал, что лицензионный софт должен быть свежим? Он должен быть лицензионным! У нас очень большая компания. Пока всех устраивает 2010 - сидим на нем. Зачем тратить деньги на новое ПО, функции которого будут просто не востребованы?
Я хорошо знаком с новыми функциями в основных продуктах Office, поэтому понимаю о чем я говорю. Да и денег на это нужно немало, а где их сейчас взять?
И логика какая-то странная. Я задал вопрос про 2010, а мне чуть ли уголовную статью не пришили. Дедукция?!
Есть такой анекдот:
Идет Петька. Видит Фурманов читает книгу.
-Ты что читаешь?

- Дедукция!
- А Что это?
- Вот у тебя дома аквариум есть?
- Есть.
- Значит дети есть?
- Есть.
- Значит жена есть?
- Есть.
- Значит ты не голубой!
  Петька два дня изумлялся  - как это можно из таких простых вещей создать целую логическую цепочку и прийти к такому выводу. Потом решил подойти к Василию Ивановичу:
- Василий Иванович, у тебя дома аквариум есть?
- Нет.
- Вот это да-а!!!

Так что не спешите со скоропалительными выводами.